# Why is this code for adding buttons programatically does not work?

Tags: android

I am trying to add some buttons to a Relative Layout programatically. I used some examples seen on StackOverflow, but for some reason I cannot understand, my code is not working: I want to have my buttons one above the other, but they end up being one on top of the other.
Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.android.myApp.MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my code:

```
    mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setText("Button0");
    btnTag.setId(0);
    btnTag.setOnClickListener(mGlobalOnCLickListener);
    mLayout.addView(btnTag, lprams);
    lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);

    btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setText("Button2");
    btnTag.setId(1);
    btnTag.setOnClickListener(mGlobalOnCLickListener);
    mLayout.addView(btnTag, lprams);
```

Comment: Use linear layout instead relative layout

Comment: OK I could try that, but I still do not understand what is wrong with my code...

Comment: The problem is in this line    `lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);`

Comment: More something like this:

Comment: p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, tv.getId());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this code....Hope this will help

mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

```
Button btnTag = new Button(this);
btnTag.setText("Button0");
btnTag.setId(10);
btnTag.setOnClickListener(mGlobalOnCLickListener);
mLayout.addView(btnTag, lprams);


lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 10);
btnTag = new Button(this);
btnTag.setText("Button2");
btnTag.setId(1);
btnTag.setOnClickListener(mGlobalOnCLickListener);
mLayout.addView(btnTag, lprams);
```

Comment: Nope, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Can you check once with different ID for first button other that "0"?

Comment: Asmita, with the new version you posted It works fine. Seems the problem was indeed in the values. Do not know why 0 and 1 or 1 and 2 do not work. Thanks a lot!!